# Solve equation with two different sets of replacement rules

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, functional

I want to solve `eqn` for `c0` in the following code.  I want to do it with both replacement rules. I realize I could just use solve twice, once for subsCoke, and once for subsPepsi.  I'm trying to do it in just one `Solve` to learn how to use *Mathematica*'s functional style better.

```
eqn = c0/(c0 + cs) == Iunk/Is
subsCoke = {cO -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3995, Is -> 0.7339};
subsPepsi = {c0 -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3915, Is -> 0.7645};
Solve[eqn  /. {subsCoke, subsPepsi}, c0]
```

Comment: The usual way is to solve it once and then use the reprules:

Comment: As in `eqn = c0/(c0 + cs) == Iunk/Is;
s = Solve[eqn, c0][[1]];
subsCoke = {cO -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3995, Is -> 0.7339};
subsPepsi = {c0 -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3915, Is -> 0.7645};
{s /. subsCoke, s /. subsPepsi}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is belisarius' comments combined into an answer

The usual way is to solve it once and then use the replacement rules:

```
eqn = c0/(c0 + cs) == Iunk/Is;
subsCoke = {cO -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3995, Is -> 0.7339}; 
subsPepsi = {c0 -> c0, cs -> 2, Iunk -> 0.3915, Is -> 0.7645};

s = Solve[eqn, c0][[1]];
{s /. subsCoke, s /. subsPepsi}
```

> ```
> {{c0 -> 2.38935}, {c0 -> 2.0992}}
> ```